# How do I define these two curves under a single parametric family of curves?

Tags: regression, parametric, mathematical-modeling, bayesian

I'm looking for a family of curves that look like a Relu

$$y = \max(0, b(x-a)) \ldots \qquad (1)$$

and looks like this:
[image: Relu (1)]

but the problem is, sometimes my data saturates, and in that case, I want to fit this curve $$y = \min(\max(0, b(x-a)), h) \ldots \qquad (2)$$

which looks like this:
[image: Relu that saturates (2)]

I came across saturated exponential model,

$$ y = \max\left(0,\ h\left(1\ -\ e^{-b\left(x-a\right)}\right)\right) \ldots\qquad (3) $$

[image: Saturated exponential model (3)]

But the problem with this model is, the slope $b$ influences the upper curvature or bend of saturation. Sometimes, my dataset can have low value of $b$ but needs a sharper bend.

You can experiment with the saturated exponential model on desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bik4xtp0b

$(1)$ and $(2)$ satisfy exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a way to parametrize them together?

Unfortunately, the Bayesian library I'm using (NumPyro), won't let me do something like this:

$$q * \max(0, b(x-a))  + (1-q) * \min(\max(0, b(x-a)), h) \ldots \qquad (4)$$ where $q$ is drawn from $Bernoulli(p)$ where $p $ prior is set to $U(0,1)$.

So, my question is, is there a way to get something like $(1)$ and $(2)$ together within a single parametric family?

Edit: In case anyone is interested in the NumPyro code, this is my post on NumPyro's forum which includes code for simulating data and fitting the model (along with the error)

https://forum.pyro.ai/t/how-to-fit-models-with-multiple-parametric-families/5080/4

Comment: When including images, please full in the "enter image description here" information for the benefit of people using screen readers.

Comment: Thanks to your good writing, I definitely understand what you'd like to do (4) but can't. But I'm not sure what "parametrize them together" means in a way that corresponds to (4).

Comment: @GregMartin added image description

Comment: @GregMartin I'm looking for a closed form equation $y = f(x, a_1, a_2 \ldots)$ where $a_i$ are the parameters and varying them can include curves from $(1)$ as well as from $(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range of the first function was $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,\infty)$, then the second function would include the first function as a special case. So let's cheat until we get into that situation!
The function $f(x) = e^{-x}$ maps $[0,\infty)$ onto $(0,1]$, and $f^{-1}(x) = -\ln x$ goes back the other way; so we can use the formula
$$
y = -\ln \max\bigl\{g,e^{-\max\{0,b(x-a)\}}\bigr\}
$$
where $g=0$ gives (1), while $g\in(0,1]$ gives (2) with $h=-\ln g$.

One can use other functions as well if it's helpful—for example, $f(x) = \frac x{x+1}$ and $f^{-1}(x) = \frac x{1-x}$.